# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

I am trying to import a file which was saved using `json.dumps` and contains tweet coordinates:

```
{
    "type": "Point", 
    "coordinates": [
        -4.62352292, 
        55.44787441
    ]
}
```

My code is:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = json.loads('/Users/JoshuaHawley/clean1.txt')
```

But each time I get the error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I want to end up extracting all the coordinates and saving them separately to a different file so they can then be mapped, but this seemingly simple problem is stopping me from doing so. I have looked at answers to similar errors but don't seem to be able to apply it to this. Any help would be appreciated as I am relatively new to python.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`json.loads()` takes a *JSON encoded string*, not a filename. You want to use `json.load()` (no `s`) instead and pass in an open file object:

```
with open('/Users/JoshuaHawley/clean1.txt') as jsonfile:
    data = json.load(jsonfile)
```

The `open()` command produces a file object that `json.load()` can then read from, to produce the decoded Python object for you. The `with` statement ensures that the file is closed again when done.

The alternative is to read the data yourself and then pass it into `json.loads()`.

Answer (score 23):

It helped for me to add "myfile.seek(0)", move the pointer to the 0 character:

```
with open(storage_path, 'r') as myfile:
    if len(myfile.readlines()) != 0:
        myfile.seek(0)
        Bank_0 = json.load(myfile)
```

Comment: Why use `readlines()` **at all**? Yes, reading from the file first puts the read position at the end of the file and so requires seeking back to the start. But if you *only* open the file and the use `json.load()` you wouldn’t be in that position in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is the first google hit on this error message, I'll document why this happened to me.

This stupid, non-descript error message also occurs when you saved your JSON file as UTF-8 with BOM, and the json decoder stumbles upon the BOM character. Possible solutions would be to save without BOM, or to specify the file encoding when opening the file.

```
with open(path, encoding="utf-8-sig") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got same type of error after reading in a json file creating from python.

Same error occurred whether i read into a string and tried json.loads() or straight from file with json.load()

In my case, it turned out to be because I had written python booleans (False/True) straight out to the file.

Trying to read them back in again caused this error.
When i modified to valid json (true/false), json.load worked fine

Didnt see any SO questions with this as a possible cause for this error so adding here for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this function (it works with data):

```py
def read_json_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        cache = f.read()
        data = eval(cache)
    return data
```

Or, you may put this in your code (it has the same effect):

```py
def read_json_file(filename):
    data = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data = [json.loads(_.replace('}]}"},', '}]}"}')) for _ in f.readlines()]
        return data
```

Comment: Dispensing with the EVAL function and using json.loads worked a treat for me. Thanks for the tip for this Python newbie, so to speak. I've written maybe 3 Python scripts to date.

Comment: These seem really weird and not general. Why `eval()`? Why the weird replace?

Comment: The trick with `eval()` works only because Python uses a compatible notation for dictionary and list definition! The use of `eval()` should be avoided generally because it can be harmful when using contents from unknown files, e.g., with a contents such as `os.rmdir('../')`.

Answer (score -2):

import json

file_path = "C:/Projects/Tryouts/books.json"

with open(file_path, 'r') as j:
contents = json.loads(j.read())
print(contents)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solution is already proposed in [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33984916/5320906).  When answering old questions, please ensure your answer provides a distinct and valuable contribution to the Q&A.