# Not sure why I got an error, this has worked before

Tags: python, json

Making a Wordle copy in Replit. I have a part where if a word is denied for not being a possible word, they can submit it to be reviewed and possibly added to the list of guessable words.
The proffered suggested to add words are then stored in a json file

here's that part of the code:

```
import json
def fetchData():
  with open('suggested.json') as f:
    collect = json.loads(f.read())
    return collect

suggest = input("\nError 2: Not in word list. Probable too obscure or too inapropriate. If you think that it should be added to the word list, type \"yes\" and it will be fowarded and reviewed.\n").lower()
if suggest == 'yes':
  newDict = {}
  newDict['suggestion']= guess
  stuff = fetchData()
  stuff.append(newDict)
  with open('survey.json','w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(stuff))
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 63, in <module>
stuff = fetchData()
  File "main.py", line 13, in fetchData
collect = json.loads(f.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
  json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

currently the json file is empty if thats important.
If you have any more questions, please ask in replies.

Comment: This post may help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984903/json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0#:~:text=json.loads()%20takes,Flag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python json.decoder.JSONDecodeError while writing to a json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65222170/python-json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-while-writing-to-a-json)

Comment: This means that the file is empty. If empty is okay, then test for that before hand. You could catch the exception, but that's not so good because you can get the same one for many different decode errors.

Comment: When the file is empty, what you would like `fetchData` to return?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a decode error on the first line and first character, that means that the file is empty. Assuming that's okay, you can just test the file size before trying to decode. I don't know what you want the default object to be, so just guessed `dict`.

```
def fetchData(filename='suggested.json'):
    if os.stat(filename).st_size == 0:
        return {} # just guessing what the default should be
    with open(filename) as f:
        return json.load(f)
```

I saved a few lines by loading directly from the file and skipping an unneeded intermediate variable before return. And 4 spaces! We are not in danger of running out of them.